# Populate column having null values in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have an excel file with two columns. How can I populate the second column if there is a value corresponding to first column. I mean,

Excel table

```
+---------+---------+
| ColumnA | ColumnB |
+---------+---------+
| A1423   |         |
+---------+---------+
| A1423   | 3689    |
+---------+---------+
| BC263   | 2846    |
+---------+---------+
| BC263   |         |
+---------+---------+
| BC263   |         |
+---------+---------+
```

Expected result:

```
+---------+---------+
| ColumnA | ColumnB |
+---------+---------+
| A1423   | 3689    |
+---------+---------+
| A1423   | 3689    |
+---------+---------+
| BC263   | 2846    |
+---------+---------+
| BC263   | 2846    |
+---------+---------+
| BC263   | 2846    |
+---------+---------+
```

I sorted `ColumnA`. Should I use VLOOKUP for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to have the result in same column `Column B` then you have to use sorting method like **Pnuts** suggested or you have to use `VBA` sub. If you wish to have result in separate column then you can use following array formula.
The Array formula needs to be added with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after entering it in the cell.

```
=IF(B2="",INDEX($B$2:$B$6,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$6=A2,IF($B$2:$B$6<>"",ROW($B$2:$B$6)-ROW($B$1),""),""),ROW($1:$1))),B2)
```

[image]

Again, you must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after putting the formula in the cell.